# Do companies accept employees who have been banned from the Google Play Console?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry

I was banned from Google Play Console several years ago. Now I am afraid that companies making mobile apps will reject me because I have been banned so their company account may be banned too as an associated account.

Is it possible for me now to find a job of Android developer? And how risky is it for the companies to accept me?

Comment: Can't you just create a new account?

Comment: "And how risky is it for the companies to accept me?" You tell us.

Comment: Your question is a bit backwards. The main risk a potential employer will see is that this documents that you have done something "bad". They probably don't want to employ someone who behaves in ways that get them banned.

Comment: Well, a colleague of mine, responsible for our IOS app, is banned from ever publishing apps via his private apple ID, because he exploited an IOS bug when he was 14.

Comment: Why they were banned is irrelevant. No point in asking. The employer wouldn't link your personal account to their corporate account, it's not necessary. You have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, According to Google Support Webpage, some common reasons for the ban are: intentionally creating Android softwares or mobile apps that contain malware, virus, spams, softwares that exploit the bugs of the Android OS, etc...

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I don't really know the actual reason of the ban. It was called "impersonation". I suppose I was banned for using words "Minecraft" in the description of my app because it simply was a software for Minecraft.

Comment: @DimaBukharev, Did Google give you a warning about using the word "Minecraft" in your description of your app before they removed your app ? (I hope Google would treat people fairly and give developers a chance to fix the problem before banning them).

Answer (score 2):

Banned as a software developer or as a player? Google wouldn’t know who a company employs, so the company has nothing to fear there.

If the prospective employer hears about it, they might ask *why exactly* you are banned, and not employ you for example if you were banned for defrauding Google’s customers. But this is all private business between you and Google, so they wouldn’t know.